# Selenium/Ruby - Error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)"

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I have searched before posting this and haven't found anything that relates to my specific issue. We use Selenium/Ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) on Windows Server 2008 R2 and tests run on IE 9/10. From time to time get this random error when executing any step. This step does not fail consistently. The previous step passes without this error. It is not the IE security settings or proxy issue as some have suggested as I have checked all these already. There was also a mention about hooks.rb already executing @browser.close and the same code getting executed in env.rb causing similar issue. It doesn't seem to be the case here in this version of Selenium. Any thoughts/help are greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much,

Comment: Please check if this related post can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575735/watir-webdriver-with-firefox-6-0-see-following-error-errnoeconnrefused?rq=1